# Applying more query conditions after calling function

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

If I have something like:

```
$users = Helpers::getUsersFollowing($user_id);
```

Where `getUsersFollowing()` looks like this:

```
public static function getUsersFollowing($user_id)
{
    return Follow::where('user_id', $user_id)
        ->select('username')
        ->get();
}
```

Is it possible to, without modifying the code in the function, apply more queries after the function call, like:

```
$users = Helpers::getUsersFollowing($user_id)
    ->with('posts')
    ->select('display_name')
    ->get();
```

I need to be able to select the display names (in addition to the usernames) and get the user's posts as well, but again, without modifying the code in the function.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you should be able to do this like this:

*as jensaronsson pointed out in the comments, this is the better solution because it doesn't result in a n+1 query*

```
$users = Helpers::getUsersFollowing($user_id);

$user->load('posts')

// Do this if you need additional query constraints
$users->load(['author' => function ($query) {
    $query->orderBy('whatever', 'asc');
}]);
```

See [Laravel Docs: Querying Relationships](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations)

For this to work your Follow-Model needs to have a relationship set up like this:

```
public function posts()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Post'); // Replace 'App\Post' with your model!
}
```

---

**The old solution (not recommended)**

```
foreach ($users as $user) {
    $user->posts()->get()
}
```

Comment: This would result in a n+1 query problem. You should eager load the posts from collection instead. as ```$users->load('posts')```